# Cache-Control public or private by default?

Tags: caching, cache-control

If I don't specify `public` or `private` directive in the `Cache-Control` header, what's the default behavior? Can it be cached by proxy servers or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found an answer to this on [webmasters.stackexchange.com](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/38175). Quote:

> See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3:
>
> ```
> The max-age directive on a response implies that the response is
> cacheable (i.e., "public") unless some other, more restrictive cache
> directive is  also present.
> ```
>
> It's conceivable (likely?) that there are
>   proxies in the wild which break this but since the only failure mode
>   could be treating a public resource as private the consequences should
>   be minimal beyond a modest performance hit. You'll have far more
>   problems with proxies which do things like cache resources far beyond
>   your specified max-age.

Comment: I'd also add info from https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.8 "When a shared cache (see section 13.7) receives a request  containing an Authorization field, it MUST NOT return the corresponding response as a reply to any other request, unless one of specific exceptions holds"

Comment: Careful reading of the MDN suggests a slightly different answer - that "public" would override the default "cacheability" of requests. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66660215/613540