# Does 'cache-control: public' actually have any effect?

Tags: caching, browser-cache, cache-control

Is `cache-control: public, max-age=60` handled any differently by any known caches than `cache-control: max-age=60`?

I've struggled to verify it, but I assume that if any `cache-control` instructions exist on a response, then it is assumed that that response is cacheable by the browser and any intermediate caches *unless* `cache-control: private` is set.

Does this mean that `cache-control: public` is redundant? Isn't this the behaviour you'd get anyway?

Comment: Hmm. Yes it would appear to, but that answer conflicts a bit with what I found below. So I'm curious which is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On more careful reading of MDN, I think I've found the answer to my own question.

*TL;DR: `cache-control: public` will explicitly override the default rules for which sort of responses are considered cacheable, so shouldn't be used lightly. Many responses normally shouldn't be cached - e.g. `POST`s or `302` redirects. See below for the full set of rules.*

From [the cache-control page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control):

> public
> The response may be stored by any cache, **even if the response is normally non-cacheable** *(emphasis mine)*.

So what does "cacheable" mean? From [the "cacheable" page on the MDN glossary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/cacheable):

> A cacheable response is an HTTP response that can be cached, that is stored to be retrieved and used later, saving a new request to the server. Not all HTTP responses can be cached, these are the following constraints for an HTTP response to be cached:
>
> - The method used in the request is itself cacheable, that is either a GET or a HEAD method. A response to a POST or PATCH request can also be cached if freshness is indicated and the Content-Location header is set, but this is rarely implemented. (For example, Firefox does not support it per https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109553.) Other methods, like PUT or DELETE are not cacheable and their result cannot be cached.
> - The status code of the response is known by the application caching, and it is considered cacheable. The following status code are cacheable: 200, 203, 204, 206, 300, 301, 404, 405, 410, 414, and 501.
> - There are *(I assume this should be **aren't**)* specific headers in the response, like Cache-Control, that prevents caching.

So it looks like one should only use `cache-control: public` when they explicitly want to override these rules for cacheability, which in general is probably not a good idea.

Comment: A response [can be cached](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234#section-3) if it specifies `max-age`, regardless of `public`/`private`.

Comment: @Joe I think you're misreading that. It seems to explicitly say that a cache MUST NOT be stored if no-store or private is present. (every one of the items in the list must be true)

Comment: You're absolute right on `no-store`; that would prevent storage. For `private`: "the "private" response directive... does not
      appear in the response, _if the cache is shared_". Your browser cache is not shared.

Comment: Oh yes I know that. I don't think that is relevant to my question. I took your response as suggesting that max-age overrides public or private in some way, which it doesn't. Private still behaves exactly as it would anyway.

Comment: Let me rephrase my comment for clarity: to be cacheable, it is sufficient for a response to specify `max-age`. Neither `public` nor `private` are necessary.